# what tabsize 'ls- C' assumes?

Tags: ls

I wanted to display the result of `ls -C` in my OpenGL application, but the output is columnized with tab characters instead of space characters. I could probably find the correct value by trial and error, but the question is where the `ls` gets this number or how does it calculate it?

```
ls / -C

bin   g\t\t      lib     lost+found  proc\tselinux  usr\tvmlinuz
boot  home\t      lib32   media\t  root\tsrv\t v\twin7
dev   initrd.img      lib64   mnt\t  run\tsys\t var\tx
etc   initrd.img.old  libx32  opt\t  sbin\ttmp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeBSD: `/usr/src/bin/ls/print.c`

```
tabwidth = 8;
```

As far as I can see, this value can't be changed, and is fixed.

GNU coreutils `src/ls.c`

```
tabsize = 8;
```

The tabsize can be set using the `TABSIZE` environment variable, or the `-T` / `--tabsize` option.

A tabsize of 8 is pretty standard with UNIX commandline utilities, but as far as I can find, this isn't standardized in POSIX.

Comment: what does "fairy function" mean?

Comment: @exebook That I'm an idiot who has trouble hitting a 'h', and hit an 'f' instead. There's only one key between them, you see!